# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

This is the error:                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference                                                                        at trainedge.alarmmanager.AlarmAdapter.getItemCount(AlarmAdapter.java:46)

This is the Adapter class where i am getting the error

```
public class AlarmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmHolder> {

    Context context;

    public AlarmAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Alarm> setItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.setItems = setItems;
    }

    ArrayList<Alarm> setItems=new ArrayList();


    @Override
    public AlarmHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.simple_card_item,parent,false);
        return new AlarmHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AlarmHolder holder, int position) {

        Alarm alarm=setItems.get(position);

        holder.tv_label.setText(alarm.getLabel());
        holder.tv_time.setText(alarm.getTine());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return setItems.size();
    }
}
```

This is the Model

```
public class Alarm {
    public String label;
    public String tine;

    public Alarm() {
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getTine() {
        return tine;
    }

    public void setTine(String tine) {
        this.tine = tine;
    }

    public Alarm(String label, String tine) {

        this.label = label;
        this.tine = tine;
    }
}
```

Comment: `setItems` is null here `public AlarmAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Alarm> setItems)`

Comment: Add the following @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return setItems != null ? setItems.size() : 0;
    }

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yes i can figure that but i don't know how to resolve it

Comment: @ChaitanyaAtkuri thanks man! the error is resolved